# Passport - Cannot read property 'isAuthenticated'

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, passport-local

I am trying to fix the following error:

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/src/util/utils.js:2
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'isAuthenticated' of undefined
    at Object.isLogged (/home/ubuntu/workspace/src/util/utils.js:2:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/src/routes/index.js:6:23)
```

I am using passport the following in my app:

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express')
//...
const session = require('express-session')
const passport = require('passport')
// configure passport
require('./config/passport')(passport)
const auth = require('./routes/auth')
const index = require('./routes/index')

const app = express()

// ...
app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'super-mega-hyper-secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
  })
)
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.currentUser = req.user
  next()
})

// routes
app.use('/', auth)
app.use('/', index)

app.listen(port, host, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on ${host}:${port}`)
})

module.exports = app
```

My passport.js file looks like the following:

```
const passport = require('passport')
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
const service = require('../service/auth')

module.exports = () => {
passport-serialize-deserialize
  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id)
  })

  passport.deserializeUser(async function(id, done) {
    const user = await service.findById(id)
    done(null, user)
  })

  passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'username',
  }, async(username, password, done) => {
    const user = await service.signin(username, password)
    done(null, user)
  }))
}
```

When my `/` gets called I am using the `isLogged()` function to control if a login is required:

```
const express = require('express')

const router = express.Router()
const utils = require('../util/utils')

router.get('/', utils.isLogged(), (req, res) => {
  res.render('dashboard')
})

module.exports = router
```

The definition of the function can be found in my `utils.js` file, where the error log above is pointing:

```
function isLogged(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    next()
  } else {
    res.redirect('/')
  }
}

module.exports = {
  isLogged,
}
```

The full code flow can be found in the following repo: [passport example](https://github.com/marcpre/learning_npm_passport)

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?`

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Because you don't pass `req`, `res` and `next` to your function: you call `utils.isLogged()` without any parameters. Thus `req` and the others are undefined.

Comment: Remove `()` from the end of `isLogged` on the `router.get` line.

Comment: @Kirk I was writing this suggestion actually synchronously to you :) I've taken longer then you -- you were first 

Comment: @Kirk and @cramopy To understand correctly, node thinks that `utils.isLogged()` is either, `req, res` or `next`. Is there a best-practice how to code this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run this code:

```
router.get('/', utils.isLogged(), (req, res) => {
  res.render('dashboard')
});
```

What happens is that `utils.isLogged()` is being executed, the *the result* of this execution is registered as a middleware.
Since you try to execute it without any parameters passed, `res` is passed as undefined and you get your error.

Now, what you really want to do is pass the function itself, not it's execution, so when express will call it (during request processing), it will pass the parameters to it. So your code should look like this:

```
router.get('/', utils.isLogged, (req, res) => {
  res.render('dashboard')
});
```